# Is it possible to define a servlet filter for a stateless ejb webservice, on GlassFish 3.1

Tags: web-services, jakarta-ee, ejb, servlet-filters

I want to export a Web-Service which was implemented as a stateless EJB. I know that these WebServices were hanled by the EJB Container, when they are annotated as @Stateless + @Webservice. Is it possible to route all incoming requests to this Webservice through a Servlet-Filter.

The Servlet-Filter works when my Java-Class is annotated @Stateful and @Webservice, or just @Webservice. But not in conjunction with @Stateless. Anyway to register a Servlet Filter for an EJB Webservice?

Many thanks!

Adem

**UPDATE:**
Solved this problem, by annotating WebService Class with

```
@WebService
@RequestScoped
```

Filter works only in this constellation and acting as Stateless class for WebService consumer.

Comment: `@RequestScoped` helped me, thanks))

Answer (score 1):

- Lifecycle Callbacks : You can have a method with `@PostConstruct` annotation which gets called after the container has initialized the bean.
- Interceptor : You can have a interceptor class which gets invoked when applied at bean class/method level by annotation `@Interceptors(ProcessMonitor.class)`.

Note : I haven't tried it in conjunction with `@Webservice`.

Comment: See updated post, pls! But I will test your suggestions if needed in future.