# Filter for @Stateless @Webservice

Tags: java, soap, filter, servlet-filters

I am trying to filter (javax.servlet.Filter) all incoming SOAP requests on all my web service end points. These web services are created from @Stateless EJB's and use `Message Authentication over SSL`

My web services are annotated like

```
@WebService
@Stateless
public class WebServiceA {
   @EJB
   private MyEJB ejbRef;
   ...
   public Result getMethodA()...
}
```

I have a custom filter that exists in my Glassfish's `lib/` directory and inside `config/default-web.xml` I have the filter mapped to `<url-patter>/*</url-pattern>`

```
public final class MyFilter implements Filter {

   @Override
   public void init()...

   @Override
   public void destroy()...

   @Override
   public void doFilter(...) {
      ...
      System.out.println("Got to Filter");
      ...
   }
}
```

The filter is called on every single request I make to the application except for my SOAP end points. The filter is hit going to the `admin console`, the filter is hit going to the `-war` files, the filter is hit when going to an `undeployed EAR`... basically everything except a deployed SOAP end point (never hits on my `WebServiceA -> getMethodA()` end point.

I also tried implementing a `SOAPHandler` but sadly this is processed AFTER the container's authentication methods are invoked `(JAAS)`, and I must alter the SOAP header before login context.

I have looked at this link [Is it possible to define a servlet filter for a stateless ejb webservice, on GlassFish 3.1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9702793/is-it-possible-to-define-a-servlet-filter-for-a-stateless-ejb-webservice-on-gla) but `@RequestScoped` does not work with `@Stateless` which is required on a `@WebService` that is apart of an ejb-jar

*Edit I tried EJBInterceptors and just like SOAPHandler, the interceptor is called after container managed security.

Thanks for any help

Answer (score 2):

Filters are used along with servlet technology. Using them with EJB/JAX WS will not intercept the requests.

What you should use is EJB interceptors which does the exact same purpose as that of filters.

Here is one sample.

```
public class MyEJBInterceptor {

    @AroundInvoke
    public Object invoke(InvocationContext context) throws Exception  {

    //Your code goes here
    }
```

To use this interceptor:

```
@Stateless
@Interceptors({MyEJBInterceptor.class})
public class MyBean implements MyBeanLocal {

    enter code here

}
```

Comment: Thank you, this sounds promising. I'll try to get an example working and if it does I will accept.

Comment: The interceptor did get called but not until after JAAS was called, I need it before. Perhaps there is a way to define priority / order?

Comment: It gets called in the order you list them in @ interceptors

Comment: that's just the order of other custom interceptors though

Comment: Web services security and JAAS are altogether 2 different things. You need to wrap your security code into interceptor.Basic authentication works just fine with REST web services.

Comment: my security code is a custom realm handled by the container, that sounds like a lot of changes

Comment: You need to find out how you can call that realm in your EJB interceptors

Comment: okay if I do that, how can I stop it from being called by the container though, sounds like I would have to remove my custom realm implementation but I cant because the GUI portion of the application is relying on that

Comment: Ohh don't remove realm. Wrap your realm code into EJB interceptors. But on the side note generally web service security is handled differently since they are external interfaces.  Are you expecting user to provide user name/password for every call?

Comment: currently clients invoke these web services with username/password in every call... the container calls my realm code before interceptors are invoked, how can get the interceptor to go first without removing the realm, which may be too risky

Comment: Please check Run as and allowed roles annotations with EJB. They would do the job you are looking for.

Comment: I am using @RolesAllowed, not sure how that helps this problem

Comment: Check Run as for the authentication . @ Roles allowed is for authorization. If done properly they will take care of security with the help of realms configured in container.

Comment: thanks for your help but I think we are talking about different stuff, even if I used @RunAs I am not sure how I would stop the container from calling the realm before calling interceptors

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/115234/discussion-between-user2286167-and-j-con).

Answer (score 1):

Aside from editing the source of Payara, I decided to disable `ws_security` by removing `Secure Service` and disabling `Message Authentication over SSL` and setting `<transport-guarantee>` to `NONE` in my `glassfish-ejb-jar.xml` This should be okay since communication to the web server is still https. Now I can create an `EJBInterceptor` or `SOAPHandler` to edit the SOAP header appropriately and then call my custom realm's login mechanism. Thanks @user2286167 for the direction.